# How to search for a value in entire document and find its siblings in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my XML

```
<OB>
<AA>
    <A>
        <id>6ed0cfce-0762-4a0b-956e-5e160a5acc2a</id>
        <title>Modernize </title>
        <description>excellence.</description>
        <createDate>2018-06-08T16:52:05.431Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>c_o</type>
        <parentTasks/>
        <subTasks>
            <id>7dd058ae-6dfb-4819-9b6e-c4e1d779525d</id>
            <id>a6654ce9-31dd-402b-b9f3-de167c8b7e93</id>
            <id>f9bb6595-085b-4090-8bb4-2222299f4779</id>
        </subTasks>
    </A>
    <A>
        <id>5895181c-ce0e-41e2-8368-e68d6d392f70</id>
        <title> cloud</title>
        <description>Customer Coast.</description>
        <createDate>2018-06-08T16:52:53.602Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>c_o</type>
        <parentTasks/>
        <subTasks>
            <id>16cf2a87-cfc5-46ae-8fa2-19192623bcd7</id>
            <id>977b8c86-dc47-435c-8274-5cfca5bffa9b</id>
            <id>7a477025-84b2-4817-a4bd-94d4463c9b86</id>
        </subTasks>
    </A>
    <A>
        <id>9f385231-8252-4b6f-87d9-e506fcbd0dca</id>
        <title>Cost </title>
        <description> create</description>
        <createDate>2018-06-08T16:50:59.510Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>c_o</type>
        <parentTasks/>
        <subTasks>
            <id>e31cacd8-aa07-4a5b-93d5-5086e7689588</id>
            <id>64a42ff3-190c-43cb-9fa4-c1aa1b4fdf66</id>
        </subTasks>
    </A>
</AA>
<CC>
    <C>
        <id>f9bb6595-085b-4090-8bb4-2222299f4779</id>
        <title>groups</title>
        <description>create</description>
        <createDate>2018-12-20T16:36:15.374Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>a_o</type>
        <outcomeId>6ed0cfce-0762-4a0b-956e-5e160a5acc2a</outcomeId>
        <parentTasks>data</parentTasks>            
        <subTasks>
            <id>7dd058ae-6dfb-4819-9b6e-c4e1d779525d</id>
        </subTasks>
    </C>
    <C>
        <id>c99ef3a5-398d-416b-8281-59d1b63ca8cd</id>
        <title>Oracle)</title>
        <description> create</description>
        <createDate>2018-12-20T16:36:28.627Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>a_o</type>
        <outcomeId/>
        <parentTasks/>
        <subTasks/>
    </C>
    <C>
        <id>21b8b637-09e4-4b33-9a97-9654ee0bd30f</id>
        <title> posture</title>
        <description>create</description>
        <createDate>2018-12-20T16:36:02.415Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>a_o</type>
        <outcomeId/>
        <parentTasks/>
        <subTasks/>
    </C>
</CC>
<BB>
    <B>
        <id>64a42ff3-190c-43cb-9fa4-c1aa1b4fdf66</id>
        <title>reporting</title>
        <description>reporting</description>
        <createDate>2018-07-19T21:48:04.225Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>s_i</type>
        <outcomeId>9f385231-8252-4b6f-87d9-e506fcbd0dca</outcomeId>
        <parentTasks>
            <id>9f385231-8252-4b6f-87d9-e506fcbd0dca</id>
        </parentTasks>            
        <subTasks>data</subTasks>
    </B>
    <B>
        <id>977b8c86-dc47-435c-8274-5cfca5bffa9b</id>
        <title>Education</title>
        <description>create</description>
        <createDate>2018-04-23T11:13:01.772Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>s_i</type>
        <outcomeId>5895181c-ce0e-41e2-8368-e68d6d392f70</outcomeId>
        <parentTasks>
                <id>5895181c-ce0e-41e2-8368-e68d6d392f70</id>
        </parentTasks>            
        <subTasks>data</subTasks>
    </B>
    <B>
        <id>7dd058ae-6dfb-4819-9b6e-c4e1d779525d</id>
        <title>launch</title>
        <description>create</description>
        <createDate>2018-11-16T13:11:18.606Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>s_i</type>
        <outcomeId>6ed0cfce-0762-4a0b-956e-5e160a5acc2a</outcomeId>
        <parentTasks>
            <id>6ed0cfce-0762-4a0b-956e-5e160a5acc2a</id>
            <id>f9bb6595-085b-4090-8bb4-2222299f4779</id>
        </parentTasks>            
        <subTasks>data</subTasks>
    </B>
    <B>
        <id>7a477025-84b2-4817-a4bd-94d4463c9b86</id>
        <title>Improvements</title>
        <description>create</description>
        <createDate>2018-11-16T13:11:18.606Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>s_i</type>
        <outcomeId>5895181c-ce0e-41e2-8368-e68d6d392f70</outcomeId>
        <parentTasks>
                <id>5895181c-ce0e-41e2-8368-e68d6d392f70</id>
        </parentTasks>            
        <subTasks>data</subTasks>
    </B>
    <B>
        <id>16cf2a87-cfc5-46ae-8fa2-19192623bcd7</id>
        <title> operations</title>
        <description>create</description>
        <createDate>2018-04-23T11:13:16.660Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>s_i</type>
        <outcomeId>5895181c-ce0e-41e2-8368-e68d6d392f70</outcomeId>
        <parentTasks>
                <id>5895181c-ce0e-41e2-8368-e68d6d392f70</id>
        </parentTasks>            
        <subTasks>data</subTasks>
    </B>
    <B>
        <id>f8a18296-254b-4400-9a55-ab3334aa682b</id>
        <title>service</title>
        <description>create</description>
        <createDate>2019-01-11T20:51:22.057Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>s_i</type>
        <outcomeId/>
        <parentTasks/>           
        <subTasks/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <id>a6654ce9-31dd-402b-b9f3-de167c8b7e93</id>
        <title>platform</title>
        <description>create</description>
        <createDate>2018-04-23T11:13:50.443Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>s_i</type>
        <outcomeId>6ed0cfce-0762-4a0b-956e-5e160a5acc2a</outcomeId>
        <parentTasks>
                <id>6ed0cfce-0762-4a0b-956e-5e160a5acc2a</id>
        </parentTasks>            
        <subTasks>data</subTasks>
    </B>
    <B>
        <id>e31cacd8-aa07-4a5b-93d5-5086e7689588</id>
        <title> Instances</title>
        <description>create</description>
        <createDate>2018-04-23T11:14:08.007Z</createDate>
        <status>In Progress</status>
        <type>s_i</type>
        <outcomeId>9f385231-8252-4b6f-87d9-e506fcbd0dca</outcomeId>
        <parentTasks>
                <id>9f385231-8252-4b6f-87d9-e506fcbd0dca</id>
        </parentTasks>            
        <subTasks>data</subTasks>
    </B>
</BB>
```

And this is the xslt

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html><body><h3>OB</h3>


<p>
<h4>A</h4>
    <xsl:for-each select="OB/AA/A">
        <p>
           <b><xsl:value-of select="position()" />.
           <xsl:value-of select="title"/></b><br/>
           Description: 
           <xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>
           CreateDate: 
           <xsl:value-of select="createDate"/><br/>
         </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
<p>
<h4>BBB</h4>
    <xsl:for-each select="OB/CC/C">
        <p>
           <b><xsl:value-of select="position()" />.
           <xsl:value-of select="title"/></b><br/>
           Description: 
           <xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>
           CreateDate: 
           <xsl:value-of select="createDate"/><br/>
         </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
    <p>

<h4>CCC</h4>
    <xsl:for-each select="OB/BB/B">
        <p>
           <b><xsl:value-of select="position()" />.
           <xsl:value-of select="title"/></b><br/>
           Description: 
           <xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>
           CreateDate: 
           <xsl:value-of select="createDate"/><br/>
         </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </p>
</body></html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the first loop `<xsl:for-each select="OB/AA/A">`, I want to loop the `subTasks`, get the value of `id`, search that value in entire document and find its corresponding `title` and `type`. Same thing I want to repeat for other loops as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a key `<xsl:key name="id" match="OB/*/*" use="id"/>` as a top level element (i.e. child of `xsl:stylesheet`/`xsl:transform`) and then use e.g. `key('id', .)/title` or `key('id', .)/type` in the context of a `subTasks/id` element to select/find a referenced grandchild of the `OB` element that has that `id` and select e.g. the `title` or `type` of it.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT keys (**`<xsl:key/>`**) provide a simple and efficient way of looking up values based on other values.

An example might help which implements above approach (provided by *Martin Honnen*) for the case given:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:key name="id" match="OB/*/*" use="id" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h3>OB</h3>
            <p>
                <h4>A</h4>
                <xsl:for-each select="OB/AA/A">
                    <p>
                        <b><xsl:value-of select="position()" />.
                       <xsl:value-of select="title"/></b><br/>
                       Description: 
                       <xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>
                       CreateDate: 
                       <xsl:value-of select="createDate"/><br/>
                       <xsl:for-each select="subTasks/id">
                            Id: <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
                            Title: <xsl:value-of select="key('id',.)/title" /><br/>
                            Type: <xsl:value-of select="key('id',.)/type" /><br/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </p>
            <p>
                <h4>BBB</h4>
                <xsl:for-each select="OB/CC/C">
                    <p>
                        <b><xsl:value-of select="position()" />.
                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/></b><br/>
                        Description: 
                        <xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>
                        CreateDate: 
                        <xsl:value-of select="createDate"/><br/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="subTasks/id">
                            Id: <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
                            Title: <xsl:value-of select="key('id',.)/title" /><br/>
                            Type: <xsl:value-of select="key('id',.)/type" /><br/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </p>
            <p>
                <h4>CCC</h4>
                <xsl:for-each select="OB/BB/B">
                    <p>
                        <b><xsl:value-of select="position()" />.
                       <xsl:value-of select="title"/></b><br/>
                       Description: 
                       <xsl:value-of select="description"/><br/>
                       CreateDate: 
                       <xsl:value-of select="createDate"/><br/>
                       <xsl:for-each select="subTasks/id">
                            Id: <xsl:value-of select="." /><br/>
                            Title: <xsl:value-of select="key('id',.)/title" /><br/>
                            Type: <xsl:value-of select="key('id',.)/type" /><br/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```